# Installing Perl Module in Apache Tomcat Server

Tags: perl, extract, perl-module

I am using archive extract library in PERL program residing in my apache_tomcat/cgi-bin folder

```
use Archive::Extract;
    ### build an Archive::Extract object ###
    my $ae=Archive::Extract->new(archive=>$zipFile);
    $ae.extract;
```

Whenever i run the program i get error

> Can't locate Archive/Extract.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
>   /usr/tik/perl/5.8.3/lib/5.8.3/sun4-solaris
>   /usr/tik/perl/5.8.3/lib/5.8.3
>   /usr/tik/perl/5.8.3/lib/site_perl/5.8.3/sun4-solaris
>   /usr/tik/perl/5.8.3/lib/site_perl/5.8.3
>   /usr/tik/perl/5.8.3/lib/site_perl .) at
>   /home/scf-17/myname/apache_1.3.26/cgi-bin/mvdb.pl line 74.

I have been researching about it and found i am missing that perl module. 
i tried install using cpan as root:

```
cpan -i Archive::Extract
```

Also i tried YUM but none of it worked.

I am connected to my server using putty... 
can you suggest other way to install perl module missing?

Comment: How is CPAN failing? What yum command did  you try? How did it fail?

Comment: cpan : command not found

Answer (score 2):

Call Tomcat's Perl's cpan, not the system cpan.

```
/usr/tik/perl/5.8.3/bin/cpan Archive::Extract
```

Comment: <pre>
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.15)
CPAN: LWP::UserAgent loaded ok (v2.031)
CPAN: Time::HiRes loaded ok (v1.59)
mkdir /tik/root/.cpan: Permission denied at /usr/tik/perl/5.8.3/lib/5.8.3/CPAN/FTP.pm line 501
</pre>

Comment: Change to the user that has write permissions.

Comment: mailed the support guys.. hope this works.. thanks for the trick daxim

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the perl/cpan that your apache tomcat server is using is the same as the one you're using on the command line. You can also check where the module is installed by typing (in the terminal):

```
perldoc -l Archive::Extract
```

This shoudl show you something like:

```
/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Archive/Extract.pm
```

And if this path '/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1' (without the Module name) doesn't exist in your @INC above, then you will need to add it to you script by adding something like this before your 'use Archive::Extract' line:

```
use lib '/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1';
use Archive::Extract;
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: latest perl version installed is /5.8.3/